# Is there a way to composer require without actually pulling the package?

Tags: composer-php

Is there a way to `composer require some/thing` without actually pulling the package?  In my workflow, it would hasten things if I knew a command to just check version requirements and update composer.json without actually doing anything with regard to the vendor directory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `--no-update` switch to avoid updating and installing new dependencies - it will only add new dependency to `composer.json`.

```
composer require --no-update symfony/symfony
```

But since `require` does not check if required package can be installed (it always pick the newest version compatible with your PHP as a constraint, without checking if it will be possible to install), this can leave `composer.json` in non-installable state. 
It will also not update `composer.lock` so `composer install` may ignore your new dependency. So this is probably a bad idea unless you want to do something with it before you commit new `composer.json`.

You may try to use `--dry-run` switch to test what will happen after `composer update` - you will be able to check if `composer.json` is installable, but `composer.lock` still will be out of date.

```
composer update --dry-run
```

Comment: This is especially useful if you have a local symbolic linked package!